# Small Poker program rewrite

Tags: c, playing-cards

I had already put up code for review a small poker program but I have rewrote it utilizing a more appropriate data structure.

How would I compare Poker hands accordingly?

[Full source repo](https://bitbucket.org/assyrian/c-small-poker-program/src/bca4ff3d97cf?at=default)

```
enum poker_hands check_hand(vector *hand) /* check what kind of poker hand player has and return a score from 1 to 10 */
{
    sort_hand(hand);
    struct Card_s *temp[MAXHAND];
    for (int t = 0; t < MAXHAND; ++t) {
        temp[t] = (struct Card_s*) vector_get(hand, t);
    }

    /* check for flushes */
    {
        bool flushsuit = true;
        for (int i = 1; i < MAXHAND; ++i) {
            if (temp[0]->nSuit != temp[i]->nSuit) { /* check if card 1 is the same suit as the rest */
                flushsuit = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if ( flushsuit ) {
            if ( temp[0]->nType == (temp[1]->nType-1) /* check if the cards increment one after the other */
                && temp[1]->nType == (temp[2]->nType-1)
                && temp[2]->nType == (temp[3]->nType-1)
                && temp[3]->nType == (temp[4]->nType-1) )
            {
                if ( temp[4]->nType == ace )
                    return royal_flush; /* found royal flush */
                else
                    return straight_flush; /* found straight flush */
            }
            return normal_flush; /* it was a normal flush */
        }
    }

    int group[MAXHAND+1]    = { 0 } ;
    int rankcount[MAXTYPES] = { 0 } ;

    for(int i = 0; i < MAXHAND; ++i) {
        int rank = temp[i]->nType;  // Get each card's type
        rankcount[rank]++;      // Increment each rank index
        group[rankcount[rank]]++;   // increment each rank's count index
    }

    if ( group[4] )
        return four_kind;

    if ( group[3] && group[2] > 1 ) // Found 3 of a kind and found another pair
        return fullhouse;

    if ( temp[0]->nType == (temp[1]->nType-1)
        && temp[1]->nType == (temp[2]->nType-1)
        && temp[2]->nType == (temp[3]->nType-1)
        && temp[3]->nType == (temp[4]->nType-1) ) {
        return straight; /* found straight */
    }

    if ( group[3] )
        return three_kind;

    if ( group[2] > 1 ) // If the 2nd index of the group[] array is more than 1, two pairs are found
        return two_pair;

    if ( group[2] )
        return pair;

    return highcard ; /* player only has a high card value */
}
```

Comment: If the main question involves unwritten code, then this is off-topic for this site.

Comment: Tags in titles are unnecessary.  It's already tagged in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Naming problem or design issue.  The first thing `check_hand()` does is to re-order the data.  I'd expect `check_hand()` to not alter `hand`, base on its name - it is a *check*.  Alternatively  just re-name it `sort_check_hand()`.   Yet later code make a copy in `temp[]`.  Better to copy into `temp[]` and then sort `temp[]`, leaving `hand[]` alone.

   ```
   //enum poker_hands check_hand(vector *hand) {
   //  sort_hand(hand);
   enum poker_hands sort_check_hand(vector *hand) {
     sort_hand(hand);
   ```
2. Code to detect a straight is redundant in flush strait and normal straight calculate.  Need only one.
3. Group detection.  Some poke like games find the best hand out of 5 cards (usual) or more (like 7 in 7 card stud) or betting order based on incomplete hands (1 to 9) cards.  A hand assessment that does not depend on 5 cards is more useful.
4. Rating.  Returning info as what kind of full house (Jacks over fives) is useful info for many games.  This code only returns `fullhouse`, `three_kind` etc, yet only needs a little more code to report the hand details.
5. Minor: Code for understanding.  By decrementing the smaller group count, `group[2]` only reports the numbers of pairs, not the *sum* of numbers of pairs, triples and 4-of-a kind.

   ```
   // original
   for(int i = 0; i < MAXHAND; ++i) {
     int rank = temp[i]->nType;  // Get each card's type
     rankcount[rank]++;      // Increment each rank index
     group[rankcount[rank]]++;   // increment each rank's count index
   }

   if ( group[3] && group[2] > 1 ) // Found 3 of a kind and found another pair
     return fullhouse;

   // suggested revision
   for(int i = 0; i < MAXHAND; ++i) {
     int rank = temp[i]->nType;
     group[rankcount[rank]]--;   // add
     rankcount[rank]++;
     group[rankcount[rank]]++;
   }

   if (group[3] > 0 && group[2] > 0) {
     return fullhouse;
   ```

Answer (score 1):

## Naming

I'm seeing a lot of magic numbers and a lot of comments that are explaining *what* is happening rather than *why* it's happening. That's usually an indication that you need to name things better.

For example, `temp` is a very generic name. Temporary what? It appears to be the cards from the hand. Why not name it `cards`?

I would also create constants for your `group` array to make it more clear that that array holds the number of singles, pairs, three-of-a-kinds and four-of-a-kinds.

On the other hand your return values are named pretty well. Nice work!

## Functions

I see 2 things that make me think you need to have more functions:

1. You have made a scope within your function and put a bunch of logic in there to separate it out from the rest of the function. And then you commented it to say what it's doing. It should just be a properly named function.
2. You have the same `for` loop repeated in that scope and again down below. Make it a function and only write it once, but call it twice

The `for` loop should be put into a function called something like `isStraight()` that returns true if it's a straight, otherwise false.

The block you have separated out should be a function that returns whether it's a flush and if so, what type. Something like this:

```
bool isStraight(struct Cards_s* const cards[MAXHAND])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < MAXHAND - 1; ++i)
    {
        if (cards [ i ]->nType != cards [ i + 1 ]->nType)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    return true;
}

bool isFlush(struct Cards_s* const cards [ MAXHAND ], enum poker_hand* flushType)
{
    bool flushsuit = true;
    for (int i = 1; i < MAXHAND; ++i) {
        if (cards [ 0 ]->nSuit != cards [ i ]->nSuit) {
            flushsuit = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    if (flushsuit)
    {
        if (isStraight(cards))
        {
            if (cards [ 4 ]->nType == ace)
            {
                *flushType = royal_flush;
            }
            else
            {
                *flushType = straight_flush;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            *flushType = normal_flush;
        }
        
        return true;
    }
    
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Hmmm `flushsuit`, at first glance, looks like `flushs*it`. ;-)